# Unable to add JComponents using methods to my constructor

Tags: java, jpanel, inner-classes

I have a problem with this nested class of mine. I can't add my JComponents to my panels for some reason in the constructor. It gives an error of

`The method of add(JComponent, String) is undefined for the HomePanel.inputFrame`

The HomePanel is the outer class while inputFrame is my inner class. My methods return JComponents and I am able to add it to my outer class but my inner class just doesn't allow it so I decided to just use `add.(enterButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH)` which doesn't give any errors but when I try to use this inner class from mainWindow class, it says

`The method add(JComponent) in the type container is not applicable for the arguments (HomePanel.inputFrame)`

But the problem is I can use the outer class from mainWindow class which makes it confusing as to what went wrong. Is it due to it being an inner class or my order is wrong?

**mainWindow class**

```
public class mainWindow extends JFrame{
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    private JFrame mainPage = new JFrame("Food Expiry");
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cl);
    private static final String homePage = "HomePage";
    private static final String expiryDateEntry = "Expiry Date Entry";
    private JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    public JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    HomePanel getGui = new HomePanel();
    HomePanel.inputFrame nextPane = getGui.new inputFrame();
    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
    public mainWindow(){
       mainPage.setSize(500, 300);
       mainPage.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       mainPage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       mainPage.add(mainPanel);
       mainPage.setVisible(true);
    }
    protected void mainPanel(){
        card1.add(getGui);
    }
    protected void getInput(){
        card2.add(nextPane);
    }
}
```

**HomePanel**

```
public class HomePanel extends JPanel{
private JButton inputButton, storeButton;
private JLabel label, itemLabel;
private JPanel textAreaPanel, buttonPanel, labelPanel;
private JTextField itemField, itemCategory, expiryDate;


public HomePanel(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(getLabelPanel("Home"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
protected JComponent getButtonPanel(){
    //add some buttons to a buttonPanel
    return buttonPanel;
}
protected JComponent getLabelPanel(String topText){
    //labelPanel
    return labelPanel;
}

class inputFrame {
    private JLabel categoryLabel, expiryLabel;
    private JButton enter, back;


    protected JComponent getInputFrame(){
        textAreaPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textAreaPanel, 
        BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        itemLabel = new JLabel("Item Name: ");
        itemField = new JTextField(15);
        textAreaPanel.add(itemLabel);
        textAreaPanel.add(itemField);

        categoryLabel = new JLabel("Category Name: ");
        itemCategory = new JTextField(33);
        textAreaPanel.add(categoryLabel);
        textAreaPanel.add(itemCategory);

        expiryLabel = new JLabel("Expiry Date: ");
        expiryDate = new JTextField(33);
        textAreaPanel.add(expiryLabel);
        textAreaPanel.add(expiryDate);

        return textAreaPanel;
    }
    protected JComponent enterButton(){
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        enter = new JButton("Enter");
        back = new JButton("Back");
        enter.addActionListener(new getInput());
        back.addActionListener(new previousFrame());
        buttonPanel.add(back);
        buttonPanel.add(enter);
        return buttonPanel;
    }
    public inputFrame(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(getLabelPanel("Expiry Date Entry"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(getInputFrame(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(enterButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    }
```

I couldn't find any duplicates on this question and if anyone is able to find any, please do link it in the comments or answer it. Thank you.

Comment: `inputFrame` isn't a component of any time, it's a plain old object

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not to be rude, but why was I able to call it in my other function mainPanel() while by using this inner class, it can't seem to do it. I understand it is an object but is there any specific reasons for one to be able to call while the other isn't?

Comment: `getGUI` is an instance of `HomePanel` which extends from `JPanel`. `nextPane` is an instance of  `HomePanel.inputFrame` which extends `Object`, `inputFrame` is NOT a component and can not be added to containers

Comment: In it's current state, `inputFrame` will modify the instance of `HomePanel` to which it belongs (was instantiated from), instead of, as I suspect you think it should do, modify itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer So that means the object in some way should be changed to a JPanel by extending it or just directly changing it right?

Comment: Yep, `inputFrame` should extend from (at least) `JComponent` - based on your current implemention

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot man! If you could answer then I can accept it as well. Would it be too repetitive to extend twice from the JPanel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on...

```
public class HomePanel extends JPanel{
    //...
    class inputFrame {
        //...
  }
}
```

`inputFrame` extends (by default) from `Object`, making it compatible with `Container#add`, which expects some class which extends from `Component`.

Based on the current implementation, `inputFrame` is actually modifying the state of the instance of `HomePanel` from which it was instantiated, rather then adding components to itself

Something like...

```
public class HomePanel extends JPanel{
    //...
    class inputFrame extends JPanel {
        //...
  }
}
```

should alleviate the most pressing issues